# PYTHON - pivot multiple columns, but separately

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I want to pivot my data by multiple columns, but i want the metrics to be aggregated for them "separately". What i have so far :

**DATA** :

[image]

**PIVOT :**
[image]

I flatten the columns and get this :

df_account_pivot_table.columns = df_account_pivot_table.columns.to_series().str.join('_')

[image]

But what i really want is that the metrics are calculated for the columns separately. e.g. MARGIN by each product-category values and margin by each gender value, and then same with sales. Not a combined margin-category-gender value.

Any tips are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `groupby.agg`?

Comment: are you sure `MARGIN_UNKNOWN_GENDER` is 1.62?  looks like this number is disregarding CHILDREN category.  However, when you aggregate UNKNOWN_CATEGORY, you are summing both FEMALE and UNKNOWN_GENDER. Similar for `SALES`